# How To Read RBG-Pixel values from CGImage in ios

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

How I can Read the RGB-Pixel by Pixel values from CGImagea also after how to assign it to UIImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read RGB pixel values with MonoTouch you can use the code posted in the answer to the following post (works fine for me):

[Retrieving a pixel alpha value for a UIImage (MonoTouch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597198/retrieving-a-pixel-alpha-value-for-a-uiimage-monotouch)

You can also find the following post useful:

[Transparent PNGs in Monotouch for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254215/transparent-pngs-in-monotouch-for-ios)

And here is a link to a working implementation of mine of a convolution filter, that reads and demultiplies the pixel's rgb values (on iOS all images with alpha channel are stored in a premultiplied-alpha format):

[How to Optimize this Image convolution filter Method in MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625582/how-to-optimize-this-image-convolution-filter-method-in-monotouch)

Remember that reading pixel values is very slow, even if you use the trick to create a bitmap context of only 1x1 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

according [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) Bitmap is used to work with images defined by pixel data.

```
yourimage= new Bitmap(@"image address", true);

    int x, y;

    // Loop through the images
    for(x=0; x<yourimage.Width; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<yourimage.Height; y++)
        {
            //Get Pixel Color
            Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x, y);
            Color yourColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, 0, 0);
            //Set Pixel Color
            yourimage.SetPixel(x, y, yourColor );
```

Comment: your right but i want solution for monotouch I knw c# support Bitmap class but this class has no support in monotouch

Comment: Not sure if at the point of the above comment MT didn't support Bitmap class, but this solution now works almost flawlessly. The only thing different is

`yourimage = new Bitmap(myUIImage);`

Comment: Not sure what the deal is with my above comment, but it appears that Bitmap class no longer exists for MT.